# How to create plot from train and test target

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a single figure that plot my `y_train` and `y_pred` with date as x-axis. I have never created the one like this before so i'm kind of confused. How could i create it like the example of figure below? So far i'm only able to create similar figure but the line does not connected, how to make it connected?

[image: this image]

```
X = np.array(covid.drop(['acc_deceased'],1))
y = np.array(covid['acc_deceased'])

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,
                                                 shuffle = False)

lr = LinearRegression()

lr.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)

pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns = ['y_pred'])
train = pd.DataFrame(y_train,columns = ['y_train'])
final = pd.concat([train,pred],ignore_index=True,sort=False)
final = final.set_index(covid.index)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(x=final.index, y=final['y_train'])
sns.lineplot(x=final.index, y=final['y_pred'])
plt.legend(['y_train','y_pred','y_test'],
            loc='upper left')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

This is my figure

[image: my figure]

Comment: You're only predicting on the 20% of the original input you split off for testing. You need to predict on x values from 2020-03-25 and on to get the lines to match up like in the example.

Comment: is it possible? how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want to do is something like:

```
X = np.array(covid.drop(['acc_deceased'],1))
y = np.array(covid['acc_deceased'])

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,
                                                 shuffle = False)

lr = LinearRegression()

lr.fit(X_train,y_train)

# predict on the portion you want to plot
########################################
pred_slice = # the x range you are after, 
             # i.e. np.atleast_2d(['2020-03-25',...]).T
y_pred = lr.predict(pred_slice)
########################################

pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns = ['y_pred'])
train = pd.DataFrame(y_train,columns = ['y_train'])
final = pd.concat([train,pred],ignore_index=True,sort=False)
final = final.set_index(covid.index)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(x=final.index, y=final['y_train'])
sns.lineplot(x=final.index, y=final['y_pred'])
plt.legend(['y_train','y_pred','y_test'],
            loc='upper left')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

**However**
,you should additionally take some steps to validate your model.

To do this you can draw predictions from the test data and use sklearn's built in [metrics](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-linear-regression-in-python-with-scikit-learn-83a8f7ae2b4f):

```
y_pred_test = lr.predict(X_test)
rmse = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_test)))
print(rmse)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: is it possible that the pred slice based on the X_test that is extended?

Comment: I don't think so, based on what you've provided it looks like you don't have input data where the gap is between y_train and y_predict. If that is the case then you need to predict on that range to get values to plot. X_test can't cover that range because the test data can only be values you have both input and output for.